# Zoom picture via animate() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've got a question about `animate()` from `jQuery`. I know how to zoom in a picture in a simple way with `animate()`. But I want to do another thing.

I want to zoom in a picture in four sides. For example, I've clicked on the picture and it zoomed like this:

- 50% to the left
- 50% to the right
- 50% to the top
- 50% to the bottom

Comment: Add proper mark up.

Comment: SOF is not a free coding service. what do you have so far? just the question title? what did you have and what is the exact problem you are facing?